# RuntimeException and InflateException: Binary XML file line #7 .. followed by ClassCastException

Tags: java, android, xml, google-glass, google-gdk

There are multiple questions about this problem, but none of the fixes I've read about seems to be working.

**Fixes that didn't seem to work:**

[Fix 1: Android - InflateException: Binary XML file line #7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368002/android-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-7)

[Fix 2: InflateException Binary XML file at line #7: Error inflating class fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709303/inflateexception-binary-xml-file-at-line-7-error-inflating-class-fragment)

**Description of my problem:**

I'm trying in incorporate a SliderView in my glassware. SliderView can be used as a custom loading screen.

[1. Link I found](https://github.com/pif/glass-progress-bar) - [2. Google Review Team Proposed Link](https://github.com/w9jds/GDK-ProgressBar)

I'm currently using the first link.

During my application, I call upon **SearchActivity.java** which does a few things. I've commented most of the code to see the problem and it seems the problem first appears here:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {

        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Here is what can be found in my **activity_main.xml:**  located in my *res/layout/* :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

<!-- The line right under is line number 7 -->
    <com.google.android.glass.sample.apidemo.card.SliderView
        android:id="@+id/indeterm_slider"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/banner_150"
        android:src="@drawable/websurg_icon_white_150" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Yes, my SliderView is located in my `com.google.android.glass.sample.apidemo.card` package.
Yes, my SliderView does have the three different required constructors.

```
public SliderView(Context paramContext) {
    this(paramContext, null);
}

public SliderView(Context paramContext, AttributeSet paramAttributeSet) {
    this(paramContext, paramAttributeSet, 0);
}

public SliderView(Context paramContext, AttributeSet paramAttributeSet, int paramInt) {
    super(paramContext, paramAttributeSet, paramInt);
    LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.slider, this);
    this.slider = findViewById(R.id.slider_control);
    this.indeterminateSlider = ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.indeterm_slider));
    hideSlider(false);
    hideIndeterminateSlider(false);
}
```

I'm getting two specific problems and that is:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.google.android.glass.sample.apidement/com.google.android.glass.sample.apidemeo.card.SearchActivity}:

and

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error
>   inflating class
>   com.google.android.glass.sample.apidemo.card.SliderView

**LogCat Errors:**

```
11-25 14:39:00.037: W/dalvikvm(3900): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41641bd8)
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900): Process: com.google.android.glass.sample.apidemo, PID: 3900
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.glass.sample.apidemo/com.google.android.glass.sample.apidemo.card.SearchActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.google.android.glass.sample.apidemo.card.SliderView
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2224)
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2273)
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1236)
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.google.android.glass.sample.apidemo.card.SliderView
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:294)
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900):     at com.google.android.glass.sample.apidemo.card.SearchActivity.onCreate(SearchActivity.java:80)
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5235)
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1089)
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2188)
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900):     ... 11 more
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900):     ... 22 more
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.glass.sample.apidemo.card.SliderView cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900):     at com.google.android.glass.sample.apidemo.card.SliderView.<init>(SliderView.java:52)
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900):     at com.google.android.glass.sample.apidemo.card.SliderView.<init>(SliderView.java:45)
11-25 14:39:00.044: E/AndroidRuntime(3900):     ... 25 more
```

So my question is, what is causing these errors? What do I need to change for it to work?

**UPDATE:**

```
LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.slider, this);
        this.slider = findViewById(R.id.slider_control);
        this.indeterminateSlider = ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.indeterm_slider));
```

This is the default *res/layout/slider* xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/slider_bar_height" >

    <View
        android:id="@id/slider_control"
        android:layout_width="0.0px"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/slider_bar_height"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/indeterminate_slider"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/slider_bar_height"
        android:background="@drawable/slider_indeterminate" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Clean and rebuild to fix the case if your view ids are out of sync between `R` and binary XML files.

Comment: Any reasons for using a custom `View` instead of the [`Slider` API](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/slider)?

Comment: I attempted to publish my glassware and the review team didn't mention the api. They just gave me a message and a link towards github to create progressbars. I don't know if this answers your question or not.
"Eventually, we hope to have the progress bars easier to build with the GDK. Until that time, check out this sample from one of our Explorers: https://github.com/w9jds/GDK-ProgressBar. "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**
The solution was the following:

In your SliderView.java constructor ( `public SliderView(Context paramContext, AttributeSet paramAttributeSet, int paramInt)` ):

Change:

```
this.indeterminateSlider = ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.indeterm_slider));
```

to:

```
this.indeterminateSlider = ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.indeterminate_slider));
```

In your slider.xml (located in *res/layout/* ) :

Change:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@id/indeterminate_slider" [...] />
```

To:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/indeterminate_slider" [...] />
```

The main problem is getting your SliderView.java to point to the right id. Since this wasn't done you were getting a InflateException. Once that was fixed, you were getting a ClassCastException. This came from your slider.xml not having that **+**

`indeterm_slider` is the `SliderView`, and you are casting to `ImageView`. You got the `InflateException` because your view can not be created due of this `ClassCastException`

Comment: What would you recommend I do?

Comment: assign an id to ImageView and look for the correct id?

Comment: Working on it, I'll let you know if it works or not.

Comment: I mean, `android:id="@id/indeterminate_slider"`, should probably be `android:id="@+id/indeterminate_slider"`, and you should look for `indeterminate_slider` not for `indeterm_slider`

Comment: yeah sorry. My head is fuzzy. Been working on this thing all day. Ok, it seems that it was indeterminate instead of indeterm. Now I just need to take care of the cast exception.

Comment: no worries. I need to understand what code are you running in order to understand, or at least to try, what the problem is. have you tried to clean an rebuild the project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65616/discussion-between-grimbode-and-blackbelt).

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the new [`Slider`](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/widget/Slider) API that was released in XE22. It is much easier to use and doesn't require you to alter your layouts since it is treated as a global UI component.